# Como manejar un checkbox en react si quiero q ciertas cajas ya me aparezcan tildadas

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox

Tengo un formulario para editar productos,  por lo cual quiero mostrarle al usuario  la informacion actual de la BD que el va a editar, deseo que en el checkbox me aparezca tildado lo q ya estaba seleccionado pero no puedo hacer q el estado cambie cuando lo quiere destildar.

este es el código q cambia el estado

```javascript
function handlerDiets(e) {
    if (e.target.checked) {
        setInput({
            ...input,
            ids_diets: [...input.ids_diets, e.target.value],
        });
    } else {
        setInput({
            ...input,
            ids_diets: [...input.ids_diets.filter((a) => a !== e.target.value)],
        });
    }
}
```

y este es el checkBox

```javascript
{
    dietas.map((e, i) => (
        <div class="form-check" key={i}>
            <label
                onChange={(e) => handlerDiets(e)}
                key={e.id}
                class="form-check-label"
            >
                <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    value={e.id}
                    name={e.name}
                    class="form-check-input" />
                {e.name}
            </label>
        </div>
    ))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

David, te paso tu código con algunos cambios para lograr el funcionamiento deseado:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const dietas = [
    { id: 1, name: "dieta1" },
    { id: 2, name: "dieta2" },
    { id: 3, name: "dieta3" }
  ];

  const [input, setInput] = useState({ ids_diets: [1, 2] });

  function handlerDiets(e) {
    const checked = e.target.checked;
    const value = e.target.value;

    const new_ids_diets = checked
      ? [...input.ids_diets, value]
      : [...input.ids_diets.filter((id) => id !== value)];

    setInput({ ...input, ids_diets: new_ids_diets });
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {dietas.map((diet, index) => (
        <div className="form-check" key={index}>
          <label key={diet.id} className="form-check-label">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              checked={input.ids_diets.includes(diet.id)}
              value={diet.id}
              name={diet.name}
              onChange={handlerDiets}
              className="form-check-input"
            />
            {diet.name}
          </label>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Ante cualquier duda, sugiero le des un repaso a la documentación para comprender mejor el funcionamiento de los inputs y los componentes controlados en React: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

Como sugerencia de mejora, trata de usar variables siempre en el mismo idioma, y nombres más significativos que mejoren la lectura del código.
En este caso, traté de mantener los nombres que tu utilizaste para no confundir.

Saludos!